# Including a file via variable

Tags: php, include, variables

This seems like the most basic thing in the world, but I don't know PHP.

I am trying to include a file on my page, and the directory of that file is specified inside of a variable.

```
<?php
    $pageGroup = 'news';
    $directory = 'http://localhost:8888/includes/'.$pageGroup.'/rightCol.html';
    include($directory);
?>
```

When I `echo` the results of `$directory`, I get "http://localhost:8888/includes/news/rightCol.html", which is exactly right.  Yet when I try to include the file at that directory, nothing happens.  I am assuming this has something to do with the include syntax.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: 1. you're trying to include not a file but url 2. turn error displaying/reporting on to see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) settings turned on from php.ini.

Having said that, there are security risks attached to that, see:

- [allow_url_fopen Security](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_fopen.html)

**Suggestion:**

To include files, don't use complete url path, use just file/folder paths.

**Example:**

```
include "/includes/news/rightCol.html"; // get from specified dir
include "../rightCol.html"; // get from parent dir
include "../../rightCol.html"; // get from parent parent dir
```

To include files from root, you might want to prefix your path with:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: This code will appear on several different pages inside several different directories and subdirectories...would `/includes/news/rightCol.html` always navigate to the same spot in PHP?

Comment: allow_url_include has to be on too. But it certainly is a security risk. And including local file with variable name can be also dangerous.

Comment: @Squirkle: It depends on the path of your current script. You can either use `../` to specify directories up level or use absolute path `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . /includes/news/rightCol.html;`.

Comment: Ahh.  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'includes/'.$pageGroup.'rightCol.html'` does the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to include a http:// resource because of security concerns. Rather than you need to get it's contents via [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) but if this is a simple page element you can use include without the full url.

Comment: if the page I am at is 'http://localhost:8888/news/' how do traverse up to '/includes'?  I understand that PHP doesn't recognize `/` to go back to the site root as with HTML...

Comment: fabrik: Yes you can. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Comment: Yes, basically it's an eval where you can't check what will be evaluated.